# How to make Auto Clicker

Tags: ads

Can someone give me a ready project or a codes how to make a Auto Clicker sure with that features:

- Choose Location (X:Y)
- Allow user to select location easyily (X:Y)
- Auto keyboard Key press
- Time (In miliseconds or seconds)

If the program/SC you give me they don't contain these features don't worry. Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwflags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cbuttons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
    Private Const mouseclickup = 4
    Private Const mouseclickdown = 2
    Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vkey As Long) As Integer
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y)
    Label1.Text = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X
    Label2.Text = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y

    Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)

    mouse_event(mouseclickdown, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    mouse_event(mouseclickup, 0, 0, 0, 0)

    Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = New Point(Label1.Text, Label2.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    Dim hotkey As Boolean
    hotkey = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F1)
    If hotkey = True Then Timer1.Start()
    Dim hotkey1 As Boolean
    hotkey1 = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F2)
    If hotkey1 = True Then Timer1.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
    Dim Posicion As Boolean
    Posicion = GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F3)
    If Posicion = True Then
        TextBox1.Text = MousePosition.X : TextBox2.Text = MousePosition.Y
    End If
    If Posicion = False Then
    End If
 End Sub
End Class
```